# Reverse proxy application and its static files with Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, web-applications, static-content, static-files

I am trying to do something that seems to me very simple but I must be stupid or miss something very obvious because I cannot figure it out.

I want to access the multiple web applications running on my server with a unique prefix for each one of them:

```
http://mywebserver/app1 -> localhost:9001
http://mywebserver/app2 -> localhost:9002
...
```

From what I understood, I need to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy, so I did that:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mywebserver;

  location /app1{
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
  }
  ...
}
```

This configuration allows me to access the homepage of the application at `http://mywebserver/app1`, but the static content is not loaded.

When I open the console of my browser, I can see that it is trying to get the resources from `http://mywebserver/static/custom/index.js` and not something like `http://mywebserver/app1/static/custom/index.js`.

I tried to add a `root` directive in the location block to serve the static but it is not taken into account since the static content request is made on `/` and not on `/app1`.

How to fix this? Is there something obvious I am missing or I did I completely misunderstood the concept of reverse proxy?

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing location /app1 to /app1/ (trailing slash). The current location will not match subdirectories ;)

Comment: Omg, the /app1/ did the trick... Thanks a lot !
@RichardSmith I find it very weird to have to change the code of the application, it seems to completely defeat the purpose of the reverse proxy...

Comment: Clearly we saw different questions ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The suggestion from @sikian did the trick, I changed the location declaration from `location /app1 { ... }` to `location /app1/ { ... }`.

The static files were served without error in the console, and the application seems to be fully working.

Comment: OMG. Shaking my head so hard. This resolved my issue of reverse proxy working but the static assets not being served up correctly. So much time I wasted!

Comment: I have the same issue and this solution not work for me. Can anyone share the complete solution? Thanks! :D